# evaluation order in regexp expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I'm trying to found female surname on the basis of regular expression from male surname in mysql database. I'm almost finished with it but there is still one bug in my regular expression and i can't figure it out what it is. The many optional characters in brackets [] are caused because the very messy database. I've already tried online debuggers with no luck.

**Source:**

Transformed from string:

```
Řezníček
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `female`
    WHERE (sex= 'žena')
      AND (surname REGEXP
        '^[rř].{0,1}[eéě][zž].{0,1}[nň][aeiouáéíóúěyý]*[cč][aeiouáéíóúěyý]*[k].*$')
```

**Desired output:**

```
Řezníčková
Řezníčková
Řezníčková
Řezníčková
```

**Current output:**

```
Řezníčková
Řezníková
Řezníková
Řezníčková
```

**Regexp explanation:** (somehow in mysql regexp behave differently than is common in other systems so I had to workout my solution):

```
^[rř].{0,1}[eéě]
```

*r o ř should be at the start of the sentence*

on second position should be vowel e or é or ě

.{0,1} without it it would not work as desired

---

```
[zž].{0,1}[nň]
```

*Between two not-vowels is always .{0,1} otherwise the expression doesn't work*

---

```
[nň][aeiouáéíóúěyý]*
```

*If after non vowel is vowel there is no need for another * between these rules*

---

```
[aeiouáéíóúěyý]*
```

*If the vowel appearance is not for the first in the surname it is always optional*

---

```
[cč]
[k]
```

*any other not vowel is obligatory*

---

```
.*$
```

*Because we are searching for female surnames from males we are expecting that female surnames are longer and are somehow based in male surnames. At the end of female surname are additional 3-5 characters.*

**Question:**

Why is surname 'Řezníková' in output when in expression is the c or č obligatory? Is there a way to force regexp evaluate the expression as it is and not to apply priorities? I suspect that the [cč] is somehow suppressed by *.

I'm really thankful to you guys for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's regexp does not understand multi-byte characters (`č`, etc).  Instead of checking for `c` (hex `63`) or `č` (hex `C48D`), `[cč]` checks for any of these 3 bytes:  `63 C4 8D`.  And since `C4` is a common first byte, it does match.

MariaDB's regexp does.  So switching to that is one answer.

Using `HEX(surname) REGEXP ...` *may* be an alternative for MySQL, but the regexp will be considerably messier.  To build up the hex version, you would need, for example, `(63|C48D)` where `[cč]` currently is.

Converting to `LIKE` *may* be an alternative.  Note that `e` = `é` = `ě` in most collations, so there is no need to mention anything other than `e`.  (On second thought, `LIKE` seems unlikely, since it has nothing to simulate "character classes" like `[aeiouáéíóúěyý]`.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

The hex regexp is something like

`^(72|C599)(..)?(65|C3A9|C49B)(7A|C5BE)(..)?` (etc.)  But I guess that will not work either, since `(..)?` means 0 or 1 single-byte (2 hex), yet you need 0 or 1 *character*.  So that needs replacing with `([4-7].|C...)?`.  Etc, etc.

Comment: My table has lots of columns, so the "show create table" output is really long. But if you are asking because of the collations, it is utf_czech_ci. Thank you for your response. One last thing: if I understand it correctly ([4-7].|C...){0.1} means in "normal regexp" expression .{0,1} ?

Comment: Oops, yes typo.  Also `{0,1}` is identical(?) to simply `?`.  I changed it.